# Column Name of PL/SQL Table-Type

Tags: sql, oracle, data-structures, plsql, relational-database

I have a PL/SQL table-type/associative-array in Oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE STRING_TBL IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(3000);
```

on which I can perform select queries like this

```
...
strings STRING_TBL;
...
SELECT * FROM TABLE(strings);
```

But what is the column name of that one column in the result set? That is, what would I need to put into `<name_of_only_column>` to make this query work:

```
SELECT rowid, p.<name_of_only_column>
FROM TABLE(strings) p;
```

Alternatively, if I can't do that, is there any way to alias that one column through a subselect in Oracle?

Comment: You can check this example

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165580/how-to-use-a-table-type-in-a-select-from-statement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But what is the column name of that one column in the result set?

Pseudocolumn named `column_value`.

```
-- nested table schema object type
create type t_list as table of number


select column_value
  from table(T_List(1,2,3))

  COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1 
           2 
           3
```

Note: In this case it's not allowed to use `rowid` pseudocolumn, simply because in-memory nested table does not have one.

Comment: It's a pity that the [PL/SQL collection documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS005) doesn't even mention `column_value` or anything about pseudocolumns.

Answer (score 3):

It's `column_value`, the following should work:

```
SELECT rowid, p.column_value
FROM TABLE(strings) p;
```