# How to insert data into TABLE type variable

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm expecting a lot of downvotes, since I think this is a silly question, but here it goes:

I'm attempting at inserting data into a TABLE TYPE variable. I have a pre-existing TABLE TYPE, defined as:

```
create or replace type m_code_object
 is object (m_code varchar2(25 char));

create or replace type m_code_tabletype
 is table of m_code_object;
```

and the table that I want to define based on this and insert data into, is below:

```
declare
    vtable m_code_tabletype;
begin
    insert into vtable values ('a');
    insert into vtable values ('b');
end;
```

Now, when running this in SQL Developer I get `PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` for both rows.

My understanding was that this is a table variable of type `m_code_tabletype` and that it's enough to declare it in a block before trying to insert data into it.

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong or what's missing from my understanding?

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00504

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So, this would be considered a collection? (or actually it is?). Can I have this variable sent as a parameter to a stored procedure?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu You can also look up Tom Kyte's Q&A here -> https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:14334298866128

Answer (score 15):

This is how you populate a table type of objects :

```
declare
    vtable m_code_tabletype := m_code_tabletype();
begin
    vtable.extend;
    vtable(vtable.count) := m_code_object('a');
    vtable.extend;
    vtable(vtable.count) := m_code_object('b');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
    c_varray SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
    c_varray := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
    c_varray.EXTEND(2);
    c_varray(1) := '1';
    c_varray(2) := '2';
END;
```

Or

```
DECLARE
    c_varray SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
    SELECT LEVEL BULK COLLECT INTO c_varray FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
END;
```

Comment: I need this saved into a user defined table type, not a varray. As far as I know the varray is bounded, while a table is an "unbounded array". So, I would have to know the size of the array before inserting.

Comment: It works the same for nested table. Only associative arrays behave differently

Comment: Though bounded, you can still use the .EXTEND() method to increase the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed explanation on table types [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165580/how-to-use-a-table-type-in-a-select-from-statement).

Try this:

```
 declare
    vtable m_code_tabletype;
    vrow m_code_object;     
begin
    vrow := m_code_object('a');
    vtable := m_code_tabletype(vrow);
    abs_test(vtable);
end;
```

In order to pass a table type to a stored procedure:

```
Create or replace procedure abs_test(mct IN m_code_tabletype)
AS
BEGIN
    FOR i in 1..mct.count
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('hello' || to_char(mct.count));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Can I have this table sent to a procedure as parameter?

Comment: My understanding is that yet. I will edit my response.