# Oracle 11g PLSQL collections in SELECT statement

Tags: select, plsql, collections, oracle11g

I have a collection of type table in PLSQL begin block and I had to use it multiple time in my code.

I there any way to use the list (table type) in SELECT statement? 
My goal is to write less code.

I have included the array (TABLE) directly inside the SELECT statement

Bellow script is shown what I'm trying to do, but apparently, I can no do that, because we can't use collections in SQL statement (Please check the delete statement).

```
clear Screen
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET linesize 300
SET timing ON

WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT failure ROLLBACK;
WHENEVER oserror EXIT failure ROLLBACK;

DECLARE
    code_groupe            VARCHAR2 (50 CHAR);
    code_grp               VARCHAR2 (4 CHAR);
    TYPE arrayList is table of varchar2(50);
    site_code_ls arrayList;
BEGIN
    code_grp          := 'ABDE';
    site_code_ls      := arrayList ('D','C','B','A','L');
    DELETE CARP.PLACES_GROUPS
     WHERE CODE_GROUPE = code_grp AND CODE_PLACE NOT IN (SELECT S.CODE
                                                       FROM CARP.PLACE P
                                                      WHERE P.CODE_IMPLANTATION IN site_code_ls;
    COMMIT;
END;
/
exit;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a table type in a SELECT FROM statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165580/how-to-use-a-table-type-in-a-select-from-statement)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use local collections like that, but you can use `forall` which is fast, like here:

```
declare 
  type tt is table of varchar2(5);
  vt tt := tt('C', 'E', 'N', 'X');
begin 
  forall i in vt.first..vt.last 
    delete from test 
    where name = vt(i);
end;
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/tuning.htm#GUID-6D4A1425-64DD-4723-8AAE-87B0A51A2854__BABDBAAJ) you can see speed comparison of `forall` and `for ... loop`.

Answer (score 0):

if you use oracle 12c, then you should be able use a local defined collection with a `table` operator. e.g.

```
Select  * 
  from table 
 where column in(select column_value from table(PLACE_code_ls))
```

or you can create a collection as object type

```
create or replace type arrayList is table of varchar2(100);
```

and than use it  in your PLSQL block.

```
DECLARE
...
    PLACE_code_ls arrayList ; -- this is a new created global object type
...

BEGIN   
    code_grp          := '454D';
    PLACE_code_ls      := arrayList ('ABVDE','ADE','EFEF','JHGJ','JHGJH');


    DELETE CARP.assos_place_grp
     WHERE CODE_GROUPE = code_grp AND CODE_PLACE NOT IN (SELECT S.CODE
                                                       FROM CARP.PLACE S
                                                      WHERE S.CODE_IMPLANTATION IN 
                                            (select column_value from table(PLACE_code_ls)); 
                                             -- select from your collection



    COMMIT;
END;
/
```