# TABLE OF VARCHAR2 in WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

The code is simplified. I have a type:

```
   CREATE TYPE str_tab_t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
```

Here a function:

```
FUNCTION MYFUNCTION(myVar IN str_tab_t ) RETURN VARCHAR
myVar2 NUMBER; 
BEGIN
  SELECT MYCOLUMN INTO myVar2  FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOLUMN IN(SELECT * FROM myVar );
  RETURN myVar2 ;
END MYFUNCTION;
```

I wonder if it possible to call the function like this:

```
 MYFUNCTION(str_tab_t ('abc'));
```

As I'm getting error `ORA-01722`. I don't think, that it is because of wrong query. I think, I'm passing the argument in a wrong way. Could someone give me any clue? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165580/how-to-use-a-table-type-in-a-select-from-statement

Comment: Try `WHERE MYCOLUMN MEMBER OF myVar` or `WHERE MYCOLUMN IN ( SELECT * FROM TABLE(myVar) )`

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance OVERsimplified it?

Because, if table contents is something like this (i.e. *strings* in `MYCOLUMN`)

```
SQL> select * from mytable;

MYC
---
abc
def
```

and you want the function to return a **number**, then you can't select `mycolumn` (which is a string) into a `number` datatype local function variable `myvar2`. But, you can select some number (such as `1` in my example):

```
SQL> create or replace function myfunction (myvar in str_tab_t)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    myvar2 number;
  5  begin
  6    select 1 into myvar2
  7    from mytable
  8    where mycolumn in (select * from table(myvar));
  9    return myvar2;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select myfunction(str_tab_t('abc')) from dual;

MYFUNCTION(STR_TAB_T('ABC'))
----------------------------
                           1

SQL>
```

---

Or, obviously, return a different datatype:

```
SQL> create or replace function myfunction (myvar in str_tab_t)
  2    return mytable.mycolumn%type
  3  is
  4    myvar2 mytable.mycolumn%type;
  5  begin
  6    select mycolumn into myvar2
  7    from mytable
  8    where mycolumn in (select * from table(myvar));
  9    return myvar2;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.

SQL> select myfunction(str_tab_t('abc')) from dual;

MYFUNCTION(STR_TAB_T('ABC'))
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I oversimplified it. The problem is definitely related with passing the argument.

Comment: To me, it is related to RETURN value datatype, not the argument ...