# Oracle SQL - table type in cursor causing ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I have problem with my function, I'm getting *ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete* error. It's caused by table type parameter in cursor, but I've no idea how to fix it.
I've read that table type part should be assigned to a variable, but it can't be done in cursor, right? I've marked the part which causing the issue

Can anyone help? Is there any other way I can do this?

My package looks something like this:

```
 FUNCTION createCSV(DateFrom  date
                    ,DateTo    date) 
    RETURN clob IS
    
    CURSOR c_id (c_DateFrom  date
                ,c_DateTo    date) IS
      SELECT id
        FROM limits
       WHERE utcDateFrom <= NVL(c_DateTo, utcDateFrom)
         AND NVL(utcDateTo, c_DateFrom + 1) >= c_DateFrom + 1; 
    
    CURSOR c (c_DateFrom  date
             ,c_DateTo    date
             ,pc_tDatePeriods test_pkg.t_date_periods) IS -- this is table type (TYPE xx AS TABLE OF records)
        SELECT l.id                                                limit_id  
              ,TO_CHAR(time_cond.utcDateFrom, og_domain.cm_yyyymmddhh24mi) time_stamp_from  
              ,TO_CHAR(time_cond.utcDateTo, og_domain.cm_yyyymmddhh24mi)   time_stamp_to             
          FROM limits l     
          JOIN (SELECT limit_id, utcDateFrom, utcDateTo FROM TABLE(pc_tDatePeriods) --This part is causing the issue
               ) time_cond
            ON l.id = time_cond.limit_id
         WHERE l.utcDateFrom <= NVL(c_DateTo, l.utcDateFrom)
           AND NVL(l.utcDateTo, c_DateFrom + 1) >= c_DateFrom + 1;
        
    CSV           clob;  
    tDatePeriods  test_pkg.t_date_periods := test_pkg.t_date_periods();
  BEGIN
    FOR r_id IN c_id(DateFrom, DateTo)
    LOOP
      tDatePeriods := test_pkg.includeTimeGaps(p_Id => r_id.id); --this loop is ok
      
      FOR r IN c(DateFrom, DateTo, tDatePeriods) --here I'm getting error
      LOOP
        CSV := CSV || chr(13) || r.limit_id || ',' || r.time_stamp_from || ',' || r.time_stamp_to;
      END LOOP;
      
    END LOOP;
    
    RETURN CSV;   
  END createCSV;
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring `test_pkg.t_date_periods` on schema level instead of in package?

Comment: I see where you defined a `type`, but not where you populated the table related to the type.

Comment: I will put it as an answer so you can mark this answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem should be solved by declaring type `test_pkg.t_date_periods` on schema level instead of in package.

Similar answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5165617/3650856) but with more details.