# Oracle "IN clause" from parameter

Tags: oracle, parameters, in-clause

I'm very unfamiliar with Oracle and am just trying to get this to work.  I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573877/selecting-values-from-oracle-table-variable-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670461/does-oracle-have-an-equivalent-of-sql-servers-table-variables) but have no idea how to make it all work.  Here's what I need.  I need a proc that will accept a comma-delimited string as a parameter that I can use in the "IN clause" of the query and return a cursor result.  Is ther a way to do this in one, all-inclusive proc?  If not, what are the different steps I need to take?  Again, I apologize for my lack of knowledge of Oracle, this is just trying to get something to work real quick.

Thanks

Here's the proc (p_Scope would be the comma-delimited input):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE CU_SELECTION_ID
(
p_Scope IN varchar2,
p_ResultSet OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
is
BEGIN
OPEN p_ResultSet FOR
select
b.addr1,
b.addr2,
b.city,
b.country_code,
a.customer_no,
b.des1,
a.entity,
b.main_phone_no,
b.phone_area_code,
b.status,
b.wb_site_url,
b.zip
from
ar_customer a,
ct_addr b
where b.main_loc_flag = 'Y' and
a.customer_no = b.customer_no and
a.entity = b.cust_entity and
b.stk_loc_no = '3' and 
b.customer_no in (p_Scope);
END;
```

Comment: Have you looked into Dynamic SQL? http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Comment: Please show what you have tried already.

Comment: These are preexisting oracle procs that need the changes.  If it can be done without major structure changes, that would be preferable at this point. To answer your question, no I haven't looked into dynamic sql...i wouldn't know where to begin with that either :).

Comment: @CosCallis I've tried variations on the two links in the question...mostly trying to figure out if the in `table(cast(array as type_array))` kind of thing would work.  I will add the proc to my question, but it's back to the basic proc at this point.

Comment: @George Dynamically I'd still have to loop through the comma-delimited parameter to build up the string.  This might be viable, but I am so out of my element here that it's not even funny.  I've barely ever touched Oracle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle stored procedure with parameters for IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242771/oracle-stored-procedure-with-parameters-for-in-clause) Take a look at that question and see if the answers there fit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe there is a 'better way', but I'm not sure what it is right now...

This should work for you though:

replace:

```
b.customer_no in (p_Scope);
```

with

```
instr(p_Scope, ','||b.customer_no||',' ) > 0
```

This will search p_Scope and return a value of > 0 if b.customer_no appears in the list.

Make sure that the *first and* last character in the list is a comma (',')

(also, as a new comer to Oracle I found [Tech Republic](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/index.php) to be a very helpful quick resource.)

Comment: There probably is a more "elegant" way to do this, but this is excellent!  Works perfect and gets me passed my hump.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Won't there be issues with this if two customer numbers happen to end with the same digits (eg 12345 and 2345)? You should bracket b.customer_no with a comma on *both* sides.

Comment: @Tim, good point...will edit in a solution for that.
@Metallicraft take note of this matter and update

Comment: This is still by far simplest solution. Other solutions include pipelined functions or associative arrays - much more work + I question If any perfomance benefits from using such things. Worth mentioning about this answer - you need to pass a string like "**,32,33,**".  So commas at beginning & the end of string.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming declaration

```
create or replace type cvarchar2 as table of varchar2(4000);
```

the query

```
select * from some_table t where some_column in 
('FOO','BAR')
```

gives same result as

```
select * from some_table t where some_column in 
(select column_value from table(cvarchar2('FOO','BAR')))
```

You can use second one and pass PLSQL collection into table function. I do it this way from Java where `...table(?)` perfectly works. Explain plan seems not too bad in comparison with traditional IN clause.

Solutions based on text search with delimiters may be performance killer.

Comment: This is the recommended approach to this problem, yet it has been ignored.

Comment: Interesting article about details and pitfalls of such a solution:
http://www.pontis.biz/resources/articles/collection_card.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use it this way:

```
 SELECT * FROM MATABLE 
 WHERE MT_ID 
    IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(MYPARAM,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) 
        FROM DUAL 
        CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(MYPARAM, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL))
```

MYPARAM- '368134,181956'

Comment: How about adding a link to the oracle docs for that function?

Comment: The performance of this query is terrible. The top answer is orders of magnitude faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6629835/550198

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here's another ugly way to do it.

```
   PROCEDURE getreport (
      p_affiliates           IN       varchar2,
      p_StartDate            IN       date,
      p_EndDate              IN       date,
      p_ReturnValue         OUT       sys_refcursor
   ) IS
   BEGIN

        DECLARE
           sql_stmt          VARCHAR2(4000);
        BEGIN

          sql_stmt := 'SELECT
            FIRSTNAME,
            LASTNAME,
            ADDRESSLINE,
            SUITE,
            CITY,
            STATE,
            ZIP
        FROM 
            ORDERHEADER head
            INNER JOIN ORDERDETAIL detail 
                on head.ORDERTRACKINGLOGID = detail.ORDERTRACKINGLOGID
            INNER JOIN ORDERTRACKINGDETAIL trackdetail
                on detail.ORDERDETAILID = trackdetail.ORDERDETAILID 
                    AND head.ORDERHEADERID = trackdetail.ORDERHEADERID
            INNER JOIN AFFILIATE aff
                on trackdetail.AFFILIATEID = aff.AFFILIATEID
        WHERE
            aff.AFFILIATEID IN
            (
                select 
                    AFFILIATEID
                from 
                    AFFILIATE
                where
                    AFFILIATEID IN (' || p_affiliates || ')
            )
            AND
            head.CALENDAR_DATE >= TO_DATE( :p_StartDate )
            AND
            head.CALENDAR_DATE <= TO_DATE( :p_EndDate )    
        ORDER BY AFFILIATEID,
                AFFILIATENAME    
    ';

        OPEN p_ReturnValue for sql_stmt USING p_StartDate, p_EndDate;

        END;

    END getreport;
```