# How to select IDs in an array of IDs?

Tags: oracle, select

I have a procedure

```
PROCEDURE Pro
(
  P_IDs VARCHAR2
);
```

I want to select from a table where IDs match one of the IDs sent in P_IDs

```
SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE ID IN ( P_IDs )
```

P_IDs looks like

```
'1,2,3,4,5'
```

What are my options? I think I saw once a way to do it without using custom functions to split the string, I wanted something clean an easy to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle "IN clause" from parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629433/oracle-in-clause-from-parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it here:

- [Using a comma-separated list in an SQL query](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/comma-separated.html)

I need to convert it to a XMLTable:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(xt.column_value) FROM XMLTABLE( '1,2,3,4' ) xt
```

Example usage:

```
SELECT * FROM Questions q
WHERE q.ID IN ( SELECT TO_NUMBER(xt.column_value) FROM XMLTABLE( '1,2,3,4' ) xt )
```