# Oracle parameter and IN clause in SSRS(RDL) reports

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, oracle, reporting-services

Before marked as duplicate, I have read the following:

- [Oracle "IN clause" from parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629433/oracle-in-clause-from-parameter)
- [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)
- [problem using Oracle parameters in SELECT IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155146/problem-using-oracle-parameters-in-select-in)

Supposed I have this query on my DataSource in my .rdl report published in our report server:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE c.cluster_cd IN (:paramClusterCD)
```

Report Builder 2.0 automatically recognized a parameter as `@paramClusterCD`. On my wpf project, I have to create a parameter with multiple values like this:

```
var arrCluster = (lbCluster.SelectedItems.Cast<CLUSTER_MSTR>().ToList()).Select(x => x.CLUSTER_CD).ToArray();
string strCluster = string.Join(",", arrCluster); // result is "1,2,3"
```

Now whenever I run(pass the parameter in the report viewer), I have this error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Workaround from the previous post won't work since this is a SSRS report.

Comment: How many entries does arrCluster have typically?

Comment: Typically 10-15. The first answer you provide might help but I want the `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION..` code of the function and how it is used. I have read the whole thread but lots of revisions and lack of true documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not going to work this way, because Oracle won't recognize that you're actually trying to pass in a list of possible values.

What you want is a query like

```
select * from t where x in (1,2,3)
```

but what your code does is

```
select * from t where x = '1,2,3'
```

As x is numeric, Oracle tries to cast '1,2,3' into a number - and fails...

Please refer to this [excellent thread at AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11%3a%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425) for correct solutions (and a sermon about the importance of bind variables).

**Update:** Tom's first answer already contains everything you need, but it used the now obsolete `THE` keyword instead of `TABLE`. So here are the steps that should work for you:

first create a type for a collection of numbers

```
create or replace type TableOfNumber as table of number;
```

then create a function that splits your string and returns your newly created collection

```
create or replace function in_list( p_string in varchar2 ) return TableOfNumber as
  l_string        long default p_string || ',';
  l_data          TableOfNumber := TableOfNumber();
  n               number;
begin
  loop
    exit when l_string is null;
    n := instr( l_string, ',' );
    l_data.extend;
    l_data(l_data.count) := to_number( substr( l_string, 1, n-1 ) );
    l_string := substr( l_string, n+1 );
  end loop;

  return l_data;
end;
```

Now you can use this function in a query:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE c.cluster_cd IN 
 (select * from TABLE (select cast(in_list(:paramClusterCD) as mytableType) from dual))
```

Comment: Can you post the detail of the function? I'm willing to give a bounty for this so please help.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try the below if you can ensure that the parameters passed is a number and if c.cluster_cd is a number column

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE to_char(c.cluster_cd) IN ((:paramClusterCD));
```