# Declare Table Variable in Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle

I'm having a heck of a time trying to find an example of this being done. I have a procedure, and as part of that procedure I want to store the results of a SELECT statement so that I can work against that set, and then use it as a reference to update the original records when it's all done.

The difficulty I'm having is in declaring the temporary table variable. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
PROCEDURE my_procedure
IS
  output_text clob;
  temp_table IS TABLE OF MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE; -- Error on this line
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO temp_table FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SOME_DATE IS NULL;

  -- Correlate results into the clob for sending to email (working)
  -- Set the SOME_DATE value of the original record set where record is in temp_table
```

I get an error on the second occurrence of `IS`, saying that it is an unexpected symbol. This suggests to me that my table variable declaration is either wrong, or in the wrong place. I've tried putting it into a `DECLARE` block after `BEGIN`, but I just get another error.

Where should this declaration go? Alternatively, if there is a better solution I'll take that too!

Comment: This blog post was helpful for me: http://imankur.blogspot.com/2013/08/oracle-sql-server-table-variable.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1 AS 
  output_text clob;
  type temp_table_type IS TABLE OF MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE; 
  temp_table temp_table_type;
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO temp_table FROM MY_TABLE;
END PROCEDURE1;
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1  ( output_text OUT clob ) IS 
  type temp_table_type IS TABLE OF MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE
    INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
  temp_table temp_table_type;
BEGIN
  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO temp_table FROM MY_TABLE;

  FOR indx IN 1 .. temp_table.COUNT 
   LOOP
       something := temp_table(indx).col_name;
   END LOOP;


END PROCEDURE1;
```

Comment: Nice one, cheers mate. So to clarify, the *type* of the table has to be declared (using the `type` keyword) before a variable of that type can be declared. However, now I'm having a problem when trying to select from the table variable - table or view does not exist. Is there some trick I'm missing?

Comment: Don't think of a PL/SQL table as being an actual table, it's an associative array.  You can create a temporary table in Oracle, and that would behave as a real database table.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem and found this:
[Selecting Values from Oracle Table Variable / Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573877/selecting-values-from-oracle-table-variable-array)

The global temporary table can be used like a regular table, but its content is only temporary (deleted at end of session/transaction) and each session has its own table content.
If you don't need dynamic SQL this can be used as good solution:

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
   (
       column1   NUMBER,
       column2   NUMBER
   )
   ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

PROCEDURE my_procedure
IS
  output_text clob;
BEGIN
  -- Clear temporary table for this session (to be sure)
  DELETE FROM temp_table;

  -- Insert data into temporary table (only for this session)
  INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE SOME_DATE IS NULL;

  -- ...
END;
```

The only disadvantages are, in my opinion, that you got another table and that the temporary table is not dynamic.