# Is it possible to rewrite this precedure using table vars

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple delete procedure which is using na cursor. I read somewhere that table vars should be preferred to cursors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SMTAPP.LF_PLAN_VYMAZ (Str_oz varchar2, Num_rok number, Num_mesiac number, Str_s_trc_id varchar2) IS
    var_LF_PLAN_ID Number(20);
    cursor cur_plan is select id from lp_plan where lf_plan_id=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
BEGIN
   select ID into var_LF_PLAN_ID from lf_plan where oz=Str_oz and rok=Num_rok and mesiac=Num_mesiac and s_trc_id=Str_s_trc_id;
   for c1 in cur_plan loop
        delete from LP_PLAN_DEN where lp_plan_id=c1.id;
   end loop;
   delete from LP_PLAN where lf_plan_id=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
   delete from LP_PLAN_HIST where LF_PLAN_ID=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
   delete from LF_PLAN where id=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what a "table var" is (I have a feeling it is a SQL Server term?) but I would not use a cursor here, I would do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SMTAPP.LF_PLAN_VYMAZ 
   (Str_oz varchar2, Num_rok number, Num_mesiac number, Str_s_trc_id varchar2)
IS
    var_LF_PLAN_ID Number(20);
BEGIN
   select ID into var_LF_PLAN_ID
   from lf_plan
   where oz=Str_oz and rok=Num_rok and mesiac=Num_mesiac
   and s_trc_id=Str_s_trc_id;

   delete from LP_PLAN_DEN where lp_plan_id in 
      (select id from lp_plan where lf_plan_id=var_LF_PLAN_ID);
   delete from LP_PLAN where lf_plan_id=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
   delete from LP_PLAN_HIST where LF_PLAN_ID=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
   delete from LF_PLAN where id=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
END;
```

**EDIT**: "Table var" is indeed a [SQL Server concept](http://odetocode.com/Articles/365.aspx)

I would code this as shown above, however since you specifically want to see how to do it with a collection, here is another way that uses one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SMTAPP.LF_PLAN_VYMAZ 
   (Str_oz varchar2, Num_rok number, Num_mesiac number, Str_s_trc_id varchar2)
IS
    var_LF_PLAN_ID Number(20);
    TYPE id_table IS TABLE OF lp_plan.id%TYPE;
    var_ids id_table_type;
BEGIN
   select ID into var_LF_PLAN_ID
   from lf_plan
   where oz=Str_oz and rok=Num_rok and mesiac=Num_mesiac
   and s_trc_id=Str_s_trc_id;

   select id from lp_plan 
   bulk collect into var_ids
   where lf_plan_id=var_LF_PLAN_ID;

   forall i in var_ids.FIRST..var_ids.LAST
     delete from LP_PLAN_DEN where lp_plan_id = var_ids(i);

   delete from LP_PLAN where lf_plan_id=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
   delete from LP_PLAN_HIST where LF_PLAN_ID=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
   delete from LF_PLAN where id=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
END;
```

This will probably not perform as well as the previous method.

Comment: It has a oracle equivalent Table Type, have you heard about it ?

Comment: No, can you post the URL for a definition of that?

Comment: I read about it in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670461/does-oracle-have-an-equivalent-of-sql-servers-table-variables/670481#670481

Comment: Maybe you mean collections?  e.g. "TYPE mytab_type IS TABLE OF mytab%ROWTYPE; l_mytab mytab_type;".  If so I don't see how they would be helpful here.

Comment: OK, so you do mean what I said in my last comment.  Not helpful for your code though.

Comment: I've read a post, where they were saying: "Use table vars/collection instead of cursors" and I saw in my proc a cursor. Therefore I was wondering if this proc could be rewritten :-)

Comment: Yes it can as I showed - but a collection would not have been helpful - possible, but not helpful.  However I will update my answer to show you how a collection COULD be used.

Comment: Thank you for your examples. Last question :-) Would you prefer to use collection over cursors ?

Comment: Not as a matter of course, no.  I would prefer to use neither (see my first example).  Sometimes you need a cursor to process a lot of data, and then it can be helpful to ALSO use collections for bulk processing in batches (FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO col LIMIT n).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not directly relevant to the point of the question, but...

I would do it as Tony suggests in most cases; but if I found myself in a situation where the cursor version was needed so some other processing could be done based on each deleted row, I'd use the `FOR UPDATE` and `WHERE CURRENT OF` functionality:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SMTAPP.LF_PLAN_VYMAZ (Str_oz varchar2, Num_rok number,
    Num_mesiac number, Str_s_trc_id varchar2)
IS
    var_LF_PLAN_ID Number(20);
    cursor cur_plan is
        select id from lp_plan where lf_plan_id=var_LF_PLAN_ID for update;
BEGIN
    select ID into var_LF_PLAN_ID
    from lf_plan
    where oz=Str_oz and rok=Num_rok and mesiac=Num_mesiac and s_trc_id=Str_s_trc_id;

    for c1 in cur_plan loop
        delete from LP_PLAN_DEN where current of cur_plan;
    end loop;

    delete from LP_PLAN where lf_plan_id=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
    delete from LP_PLAN_HIST where LF_PLAN_ID=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
    delete from LF_PLAN where id=var_LF_PLAN_ID;
END;
```

This would lock the rows you're interested it, and can make the intent of the delete clearer.

Comment: Why would be the need to use a cursor in this situation ? I thought cursors should be used as the last option, because of their locking problems.

Comment: In this situation I wouldn't, as I said I'd use Tony's subquery. But if I had to do something else inside the loop - even a dbms_output of the ID being deleted - I'd prefer to use for update/where current of. Not quite sure what you mean about locking issues - you're deleting the rows so why is locking them early a bad thing?