# What Can I use to hold multiple columns and rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Aside from cursor what function can I use to hold multiple columns and rows?

Here is my sample query

```
With a as (
     select statement
    ), as b (
     select statement
    )
```

I want to put this in one variable or anything that can hold the return columns/rows

```
select a.column1 , b.column2, b.column2 
from a , b
```

Comment: `I want to put this one variable or anything I can us to hold this` ... can you explain better what this means?

Comment: *I want to put it in one variable or anything that can hold the return columns/rows

Comment: How about a view or another CTE?

Comment: View is does not physically exist, Cursor might work but I'm getting ORA-00928

Comment: Can we see the code that returns ORA-00928? Apart from the cursor, you can also try a nested table.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is ... a table!? But assuming that's problematic, you could use a table variable or temp table. See: [Does Oracle have an equivalent of SQL Server's table variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670461/does-oracle-have-an-equivalent-of-sql-servers-table-variables)